How to heat large volume of soup without gas
I need to heat a large pot of chicken soup, I'd say around 45L (including the chicken and vegetables inside), without gas (as I need to heat it in an indoor space with no exhaust fan). I was thinking of an immersion heater, but I couldn't find anything made to heat such a a volume. And sous-vide heaters all seem to be for very small amounts of liquid, so I don't know how that would work with a large volume. And all the electrical burners looked like they couldn't heat that volume, nor could they support the weight of the pot. Does anybody have a place to get one of the aforementioned items or another idea how to heat it up? Thanks!

Do you have to do it all in a single pot? Or would separating it into multiple pots be feasible?

@fyrepenguin Sorry accidentally wrote 180 instead of 80. I could do it in smaller pots, but I would need to buy new pots...

@KovyJacob : the limit is really about how much heat each burner can put out.  You heat the same relative amount in a small pot refilling it multiple times as a large pot sitting on that same burner... so you start one large pot heating that's only partly full, then your other pots.  As the small pots get sufficiently hot, add them to the large, refill and return to the heat

@KovyJacob can you not borrow? Or even hire smaller but liftable catering-sized pans?  If you get down to 10 l, stock pots are common and can be quite cheap if you do have to buy

I think the answer to this is the same as the old joke about eating an elephant. :)

@fyrepenguin You think like a 8 inch 1500 watt burner could heat 45ish litres to near boiling over a few hours?

I don't think so.  100% efficiency would be over 3 hours from fridge temp to boiling.  It's actually dangerous to heat up food too slowly (as it gives bacteria a chance to multiply)  That's why I'd recommend heating up smaller amounts in both parallel (multiple burners) and serial (heat some, pour it into larger pot, then heat up next batch, etc)

If you REALLY have to heat this all in one pot... if you can do this outside, there are propane burners that a meant for frying turkeys, but they also work well for any large pot, or even a wok.

@joe I did some research the other day and it does seem that there are sufficiently sized induction burners available for purchase, but tbh getting one would be more expensive than more appropriately sized ones & pots. Large enough induction burners for the size mentioned seem to be more on the custom/small order/production size commercial offerings.

@fyrepenguin anything big enough would need more current than the typical electrical sockets in most countries could provide. So you'd need to check what's available on site.  I'm not aware of anywhere that routinely has sockets providing more than 16A @ 240V for a little under 4kW; domestically, bigger sockets tend to be in kitchens which should already have cookers.  The OP is apparently in Canada where high power 240V sockets of course exist - but in the right place?

@ChrisH  Canada and the U.S. uses 40 amp sockets/circuits for kitchen ranges/ovens/U.K. hobs.  So they are usually handy in the right place.

@crip659 it's not clear to me that there's actually a kitchen here (no exhaust fan, general shortage of equipment). If there's a 40A socket there's probably a cooker plugged into it - just use all of that

Not an uncommon issue in home brewing (though personally I use on a 40L pot and generally only 32-36L in it.)
I use a "canning element" on a regular 240V electric stove (not a 120V hotplate) which is something like 3200W and specially reinforced for large weighty pots.
A commercial kitchen hotplate would be similarly suitable given the commercial kitchen scale of the soup here, and will require similar power levels for reasonable heating speed. Since you are defaulting to liters you likely have 220-240V by default and simply need a hotplate of suitable power & weight rating to compliment your large pot.
Or a big gas burner outside, and carry the hot pot inside when heated (what most home brewers do.)
Some homebrewers do build high power immersion heaters using water heater elements, but that might be a bit more DIY than you have in mind, as well as potentially interacting poorly with chunks of chicken and vegetables in direct contact with the heating element. A GFCI/RCD on the supply is HIGHLY advisable if you do choose that route.

When I've had to heat large (though smaller than that) volumes it's been for serving over a significant period. Heating in smaller pans is good because you can match supply to demand, heating as you go (assuming buffet style or counter service).
This also allows you to serve from a tureen kept topped up (they're better at maintaining heat than at heating) or even use a slow cooker as a tureen.
For many soups you need to be able to stir as you reheat, or it will burn on the bottom.  Pans up to around 10 l are easy to stir right the way down with domestic utensils, 20-30 l needs longer handles.  Over about 20 l is also a lot of weight to be shifting when hot; it's an awkward lift compared to what you might be used to if you go to the gym.
With realistic power inputs, if you need it all hot at once, you're going to have  a problem using one big pan.  It will take a few  hours to heat up, spending most of that time in the danger zone. Smaller pans can be distributed over multiple burners; you could use one burner to keep a big container hot, adding smaller potfuls to it as they get hot.
Given the time taken to serve what must be at least around 100 portions, you could really do with multiple people serving, working from multiple containers.  And warmed bowls, which are going to need some time in a warm oven (but given that empty dishes aren't subject to food safety concerns, you could warm them at home and transport them in a well-insulated container)
If you did reheat the whole lot in one pan, you'd be serving from the stove, from something immovable and rather tall. Being so wide there's a lot left when it's a bit too shallow for a ladle which is also awkward

I need to put it all out at the same time, its going into larger serving bowls and then out to the tables.

You think like a 8 inch 1500 watt burner could heat 45ish litres to near boiling over a few hours?

@KovyJacob Just under 3 hours. The size of the burner doesn't matter except for balancing a pan on it. It takes 4200kJ/kg/K to heat water, and soup is mostly water. To add 80°C (e.g. from fridge cold to 85°) to 45 l therefore takes about 11MJ. With 1500W that's 10000s or 2.8 hours.

Of course you will have losses, so it will take longer, but the losses will be less in a smaller pan, and there are big food safety and practical benefit. If you tried to heat the whole lot in a massive pan it would spend a long time warm, when bacteria can grow, and you'd have to start heating 3 hours before service. Smaller pans can also be done in parallel if you have multiple burners, as I did (a small but complete domestic stove in a village hall).

But seeing your previous comment about serving all at once, multiple stock pots on multiple burners has to be the way to go. Then you can have multiple people filling bowls as well -  solo, the first would be getting cold before you'd filled the last (warming bowls is a good idea, if you can use an oven on low)
